# Pressure affecting temperature in between layers

Tags: pressure, temperature

Precured Tread rubber is mounted over a tyre which is buffed and coated with vulcanizing solvent and bonding gum. The curing process is done in an electric heating chamber. The tyre is inflated upto $100psi$ and the chamber upto $65psi$ which does the pressing of the tread rubber onto the tyre successful and the chamber is heated upto 125°C for a period of approximately 2 hours.

I wanted to mount the tyres inside the chamber and give the necessary pressure to both chamber and the tyres and keep it overnight without turning on the heaters  and then start the heating process the next morning after around 12 hours.

**My question is** by keeping the pressure on the tread rubber and the tyre for such a long period, would it cause any heat in between them? If yes then how much?  I am worried about the heat if produced, that can effect the vulcanizing solvent and the bonding gum.